# Can we set expiry for all keys in Azure Redis Cache?

Tags: c#, redis, azure-redis-cache

To set an expiry for a key as it is being created, we can use StringSetAsync and pass a timestamp value for expiry. However, this is not possible if we want to set multiple key-value-pairs at once -

```
Task<bool> StringSetAsync(KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>[] values, When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);

Task<bool> StringSetAsync(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, TimeSpan? expiry = default(TimeSpan?), When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Is it possible to set the expiry for all keys at the cache level on azure somewhere?
I could not find the answer in any documentation.
I want to set the kvps all at once to reduce the number of calls to azure redis cache. I also could not find any upper limit to this. How many keys at max can we get and set in one call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`Redis Commands`](https://redis.io/commands) list or `Related commands` (the right-side of page) list about [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire), there is not a command can expire all keys at a time.

[image]

So the only way is that you need to loop to run the command `EXPIRE <key> <seconds>` for the list from command `KEYS *`. Meanwhile, considering for reducing the number of requests, you can try to refer to the topic [`Scripting`](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Scripting) of `StackExchange.Redis` offical documents to generate a Lua script for all keys expiry and request once to expire all via command [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/EVAL).

Comment: I'll have a look at this. But making multiple parallel calls to set one key value pair seems like a better option in front of this.